# Cargar listas html usando javascript y ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

tengo un inconveniente en cuanto a rendimiento al insertar una lista usando javascript a un html ya que si bien la lista si se carga, cuando los componentes de la lista son gran cantidad es muy lento el proceso (hablo de minutos)

aqui una descripción de lo que estoy haciendo 
1. una etiqueta html en donde se cargara la lista

```
<ol id="list_planogramas" class="listasprinc" style="padding: 0px;">

</ol>
```

2. realizo una solicitud ajax la cual retorna un json con la información que quiero mostrar en la lista

```js
$(list_planogramas).html('<div style="text-align: center"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/></div>');
    llamada = $.ajax({
        data: "seleccione=" + 1,
        url: "ConsultasSW/ListaPlanogramas.php",
        type: "post",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "") {
                $(list_planogramas).html('No se han creado planogramas, para crear uno nuevo seleccione ' + '<i class="material-icons" style="color: grey;">add_circle</i>');
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    planogramas[i] = new Planogramas();
                    planogramas[i].setId = response[i].id;
                    planogramas[i].setNombre = response[i].nombre;
                    planogramas[i].setEstado = response[i].estado;
                    planogramas[i].setTipo = response[i].tip_descripcion_tipo;
                    planogramas[i].setNumeroDispensadoras = response[i].maquinas;
                    planogramas[i].setFechaCreacion = response[i].fecha;
                }
                mostrarPlanogramas(planogramas);
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

la información la guardo en un objeto "planogramas[i] = new Planogramas();"

y por ultimo realizo la lista para llevarla al html por medio de la funcion mostrarPlanogramas(planogramas);

```js
function mostrarPlanogramas(li_planogramas) {
    var html = "<div>";
    for (var i = 0; i < li_planogramas.length; i++) {
        $(list_planogramas).html(html += '<div class="cont_plano">\n\
                    <li class="enlace_lat" value="' + li_planogramas[i].getId + '" onclick="datosplanograma(' + JSON.stringify(li_planogramas[i]).replace(/\"/g, "&quot;") + ');">\n\
                        <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content list_cliente">\n\
                            <i class="material-icons mdl__list__item-icon" style="color: #212121"><img class="iconopro"src="images/iconos-planimetria.png"/></i>\n\
                            <span class="basico_cliente">\n\
                                <p class="nom_cliente" style="color: unset">'+li_planogramas[i].getNombre+'</p>\n\
                                <p class="indato">Tipo de planograma: '+li_planogramas[i].getTipo+'</p>\n\
                                <p class="indato">Fecha de creación: '+li_planogramas[i].getFechaCreacion+'</p>\n\
                            </span>\n\
                        </span>\n\
                    </li>\n\
                </div>\n\
                ');
        indice++;
    }
    html += "</div>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

todo lo hace correctamente el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una lista con la informacion...

el inconveniente como ya lo comente es que se demora mucho en cargar por ejemplo con 1500 datos y quisiera saber si es posible realizar alguna mejora para que esto sea mas rapido, cabe aclarar que cada elemento "li" al seleccionarlo al frente muestra información adicional:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo muy agradecido la ayuda que me puedan brindar...

Comment: Has chequeado en donde se tarda mas?  En el servidor o en el cliente?

Comment: Buenas ! Consulta: no has probado iterar directamente la respuesta en vez de setear de nuevo en el objecto ‘planogramas[i] = new Planogramas();’ ? Parece que estás consumiendo mucho recurso al iterar y crear nuevos objetos a partir de la respuesta . Saludos !

Comment: Lo primero de todo, te recomiendo mucho que no cargues todos los datos, sino por ejemplo 50, y que mediante un botón, puedas cargar los 50 siguientes.

Comment: Hola @alanfcm ... en el cliente, la respuesta en el lado del servidor se demora en promedio 3 segundos... creeria que es al dibujar la lista en donde se esta demorando

Comment: hola @Adán Rodriguez , te refieres a realizar la lista en el servidor? lo he probado el tiempo es prácticamente similar a si se hace en el cliente, tambien he medido cuanto se demora en crear los objetos y es muy rapido, 3 segundos en promedio, supongo que el problema es entonces al dibujar la lista y enviarla al html...

Answer (score 2):

Estas actualizando el HTML en cada iteracion.  Una mejora que puedes hacer es concatenar todo el HTML primero y hacer la asignacion una sola vez.  Algo asi:

```
function mostrarPlanogramas(li_planogramas) {
    var html = "<div>";
    for (var i = 0; i < li_planogramas.length; i++) {
        html += '<div class="cont_plano">\n\
                    <li class="enlace_lat" value="' + li_planogramas[i].getId + '" onclick="datosplanograma(' + JSON.stringify(li_planogramas[i]).replace(/\"/g, "&quot;") + ');">\n\
                        <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content list_cliente">\n\
                            <i class="material-icons mdl__list__item-icon" style="color: #212121"><img class="iconopro"src="images/iconos-planimetria.png"/></i>\n\
                            <span class="basico_cliente">\n\
                                <p class="nom_cliente" style="color: unset">'+li_planogramas[i].getNombre+'</p>\n\
                                <p class="indato">Tipo de planograma: '+li_planogramas[i].getTipo+'</p>\n\
                                <p class="indato">Fecha de creación: '+li_planogramas[i].getFechaCreacion+'</p>\n\
                            </span>\n\
                        </span>\n\
                    </li>\n\
                </div>\n\
                ';
        indice++;
    }
    html += "</div>";
    $(list_planogramas).html(html);
}
```

Comment: Ese simple cambio ha mejorado el rendimiento increible paso de muchos minutos a unos cuantos segundos... super @alanfcm